# how to have two independent views?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

is it posible to have navigationcontroller view and a subview on it (or independent view) which not moves when navigationcontroller is pushed or poped? Both views responds to user interaction.

Comment: add your main view in navigationcontroller and add another view in your main view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [container view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) this is absolutely possible.

1. Create a custom container view controller and add a subview (the view that should not move)
2. Instantiate `UINavigationController` and add it as a child view controller (using [`addChildViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW76))  of the container view controller from step 1
3. Attach `UINavigationControllers`'s view below the subview you added in step 1

After that, you're done.